# Pass parameter in ng-change function

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get information about a selected task using its id, to do so I used a function with ng-change, but i get a null value in the result and no errors here is my code :

The view :

```
<form ng-submit="ajouter.ajoutFT()">
<label>Projets:</label>
<select class="form-control" ng-change="myFunc()" ng-model="projet_id">
<option ng-repeat="projet in projetsListe" value="{{projet.IdProjet}}">{{projet.NomProjet}}</option>
</select>
<br>

<label>Tache: </label> 
<select class="form-control" name="tacheid" ng-change="specifiedTask(ajouter.ajoutData.tacheid)" ng-model="ajouter.ajoutData.tacheid">
   <option ng-repeat="t in tachelistes" value="{{t.IdTache}}">{{t.NomTache}}</option>
</select>
<br>
<span class="label label-danger"> Temps inscrit sur cette Tache : {{tempsinscri}} Temps prévu pour cette tache : {{tachelist[0].TempsPrevu}} jours </span> 
<br><br>
```

The controller :

```
 $scope.specifiedTask = function (id){
   var tempsinscri =0;
   FT.getftbyTid(id).then(function(result){
   for(var i=0;i<result.data.ftTlistes.length;i++){
     tempsinscri=tempsinscri+result.data.ftTlistes[i].TempsPasse;
   }
    $scope.ftTlistes = result.data.ftTlistes;
    $scope.tempsinscri=tempsinscri;

   });
     Tache.getTachebyId(id).then(function(result){
     $scope.tachelist = result.data.tachelistes;
   });
 }
```

My result : **Temps inscrit sur cette Tache : 0 
            Temps prévu pour cette tache :**

Is the problem related to how I pass the id ?

Comment: Need more code. Put full html or html containing `ng-repeat`

Comment: @Mr_Perfect This is all the code of that part, do you mean I need to use ng-repeat in span for ng-change to work ? (I'm a beginner in angular so I still don't understand fully its elements)

Comment: What is the value of `ajouter.ajoutData.tacheid` in `ng-change` function?

Comment: @Mr_Perfect  it's the value in ng-model , the id of the selected element  : value="{{t.IdTache}}"

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't see it clearly

Comment: @jihane Can you, in the for loop, do a `console.log(i)` and tell us the result of this please ? Because I think the reason of your problem is because `i.TempsPasse` is `undifined`

Comment: @JeanJacques thank you for your comment I realized that since result.data.ftTlistes is an object of arrays "i" only takes the first value of the array so I changed the for loop to a standard loop, now I get 0 instead of NaN but this means that my function still doesn't work since the Id is not passed correctly

Comment: @jihane So you don't have `NaN` anymore ? If yes, please edit your question to explain what's going now and if there is still a problem !

Comment: @jihane It would have been great if you had created a new section **EDIT** in your question to explain the new problem, cause now your original problem is lost and if someone gets the same problem as you he will not find it in this post, but anyway. At the end of your loop what is the result of the var tempsinscri ? 0 ?

Comment: @JeanJacques you are right , I am a new stackoverflow user so I didn't know about this possibility :) . yes the tempinscri var gets a 0 because the function doesn't get the right id so tempinscri takes the initial value which is 0

Comment: @jihane You mean that the `id` is not the value you expected to ? If so, what is its value and what value you expected ?